# Understanding Java GUI development, managing and setting JComponents

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jframe, jpanel

I wanted to have a discussion on Java GUIs, right now, I'm still in school and I've done light gui development for class.(We briefly covered it.)

Plain and simple, I couldn't do anything I want, I wanted to build a nice clean layout but everything looked off and worse when you maximize it. JButton were huge when put inside a GridLayout, or they spanned the whole row, when I clearly specified the size of the button and etc. It's been one headache after another with Java gui development.

With Microsoft WPF/XAML UI development is more straightforward, it felt like HTML/CSS. Setting the width, height, margin, and padding is great, knowing where my components are going to be puts the mind at ease. And you can even design a custom Look and Feel.

I wanted to know if do you guys have any tips and resources for someone starting Java GUI development. And the one thing I don't get is launch new items with a JFrame, i.e a game.

At Launch your directed to a panel with 4 buttons.

Play Game - Takes you to a new panel to play the game.
Lobby - Takes you to a chat like interface
and etc

Should these be panels? Or more JFrames, like when a user click a button I launch the Play Game JFrame then close the menu JFrame. I really have no ideas with Java guis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off take a look at [Mig Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/).  This is a real full featured layout manager and currently is the best one available.  If for some reason you can't use external dependencies then you will want to look at GridBagLayout.  GridBagLayout will be powerful enough to do everything you need, but it is not as easy to use as something like Mig Layout.

In 99% of the applications you will build you will have a single JFrame and just transition the JPanels to show the different screens.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you understand and are using the appropriate layout managers.  This Swing tutorial is very useful for learning how each works:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Also realize that you can layer layouts by putting on panel inside another.  This is sometimes necessary to achieve a desired effect while keeping things simple.

For your last question, buttons can just be added to a panel that can bee adding to additional panels before a frame.

Answer (score 2):

First off, one of my rules of thumb when building UI panels is to never set directly any location or size.

Then, a second rule is to never set any preferred, minimum or maximum size directly in pixels (thus will bite you when you change from one monitor to another one, with higher or lower DPI resolution). Take a look at [this post](http://jfpoilpret.blogspot.com/2009/01/swing-ui-layout-best-practices.html) on my blog, quite old but still useful today.

Thirdly, I try to avoid embedding panels into panels because it leads to components alignment problems and inconsistent component sizes.

Finally, I try to use [DesignGridLayout](http://designgridlayout.java.net/) for most of my forms, and sometimes revert to GridBagLayout if the UI layout is too complex (but a complex UI layout may also be a sign of poor UI design).

As a general comment about how to build UI applications (with any UI toolkit in general, but with Swing in particular), there are [several recommendations](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) that exist out there, but it is hard to find concrete implementations, you have to read a lot about these, and then try to find the way that works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, welcome. Compared to HTML /Javascript/CSS you can get nothing like the sophistication and polish for the equivalent level of time spent learning.

(I haven't sourced all the files for you for anything here - google and start looking up).

Swing, in my experience definitely feels like I read 10 million documents, played with some demos, and spend three or four months nightly for 2-3 hours, and you have some idea of how some of the api's work, and then have no idea why some don't. Its great. You want something to work and then implement that, and  proceed to f*ck up the rest of your gui.

Java swing, in my opinion, is desperately crying for an open source JQuery type plugin library that will animate your JComponents and render them in a way that you like. Its a definite second class citizen on the desktop, and especially now that CSS / HTML browser rendering sophistication has improved over the last few years.

The nimbus look and feel style is an improvement definitely in the right direction.

You could also move over to JavaFx. Good luck. Apparently its quite nice. I haven't yet had the time or patience.

If you are allowed to use thirdparty library : try JAXX as an option. The idea was to create a css type implementation, where styling elements are separated into a file that can be quickly configured and tested.

Read here for good introduction: today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html

JavaCSS is found in the JAXX project. JAXX is a xml format style implementation of the swing gui interface. You write an xml document, and a css style document, and are able to bind the inputs and outputs of the GUI to your java implementation engine. The css style document allows for rapid sophisticated gui development. Using the jaxx jar engine, the xml code is converted into java code that runs as rapidly as if deployed in a .java class file.

The project has been continued by a French group of programmers and is now to be found here: http://www.nuiton.org/projects/jaxx/files

The demo is at least pretty and most things seem to work.

The latest release is JAXX 2.4.2. The latest update was May or June 2011. Whilst in French, the documentation is still comprehensible in English. Just translate.

The original ethan nicholas files of jaxx were last updated on 17-07-2009

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxx/

Please note: www.jaxxframework.org/wiki/Main_Page is a dead link, the site is discontinued. instead a mirror has been made and can be found at: buix.labs.libre-entreprise.org/original-jaxx/www.jaxxframework.org/wiki/Main_Page.html

This documentation is essential to understand the meaning and purpose of jaxx and its use.

---

If you are patient, have lots of time, and are interested, also look at the timing framework by Chet Haase, to animate your components, it is possible to create sophisticated effects. It requires learning curve and time.

Or pay  to get your gui components handled by a professional third party library? (Um, the obvious answer, no-one who has spent the time and effort to learn to create a pretty gui is just gonna hand that over).

So spend three years learning and then ask for moola from others?

Another idea - I am very into exploring but it looks like it might be a nightmare to implement, despite everyone saying its so easy, get an open source webbrowser html / csss renderer embedded, and design your gui on that, using CSS / JQuery / HTML.

But it looks like you have to first compile the web browser (mozilla) from source, and then wrap that in another program (e.g. JRex) and then put the whole thing in a mini- client server like Jetty, just to have a front end implementation that you halfway like.

And that is only if the browser is actually is as compliant with the CSS2 standard and HTML4. Forget about HTML5. That is for the future.

Okay, I am grumpy today, but I don't think the gripes are completely unjustified.